# iPod Touch (4gen) camera: video same resolution as still camera?

Tags: ipod-touch, camera

I want to take a photo of something (an arm injury!), and I  think it'll be hard to hold the camera in just the right place while I hit the touchscreen-shutter.  But I could put it in video mode, and then pick out a good frame later.

Does the video taken by the iPod Touch have the same resolution/quality as a still frame captured by its camera?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit crazy, but on the 4th gen iPod touch the video is actually [*higher* resolution than the still pictures](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/specs.html):

> #### Cameras, photos, and video
>
> - Video recording, HD (720p) up to 30 frames per second with audio; still photos (960 x 720) with back camera

720p video is 1280x720, whereas the photos taken are only 960x720.